# Parameters of my network on PyTorch are not updated

Tags: pytorch

I want to make an auto calibration system using PyTorch.

I try to deal with a homogeneous transform matrix as weights of neural networks.

I write a code referring to PyTorch tutorials, but my custom parameters are not updated after backward method is called.

When I print a '**grad**' attribute of each parameter, it is a **None**.

My code is below. Is there anything wrong?

Please give any advise to me. Thank you.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

import numpy as np

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.params = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(6))
        self.rx, self.ry, self.rz = self.params[0], self.params[1], self.params[2]
        self.tx, self.ty, self.tz = self.params[3], self.params[4], self.params[5]
        

    def forward(self, x):
        tr_mat = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, self.params[3]],
                                [0, 1, 0, self.params[4]],
                                [0, 0, 1, self.params[5]],
                                [0, 0, 0, 1]], requires_grad=True)

        rz_mat = torch.tensor([[torch.cos(self.params[2]), -torch.sin(self.params[2]), 0, 0],
                                [torch.sin(self.params[2]), torch.cos(self.params[2]), 0, 0],
                                [0, 0, 1, 0],
                                [0, 0, 0, 1]], requires_grad=True)

        ry_mat = torch.tensor([[torch.cos(self.params[1]), 0, torch.sin(self.params[1]), 0],
                                [0, 1, 0, 0],
                                [-torch.sin(self.params[1]), 0, torch.cos(self.params[1]), 0],
                                [0, 0, 0, 1]], requires_grad=True)

        rx_mat = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                                [0, torch.cos(self.params[0]), -torch.sin(self.params[0]), 0],
                                [0, torch.sin(self.params[0]), torch.cos(self.params[0]), 0],
                                [0, 0, 0, 1]], requires_grad=True)

        tf1 = torch.matmul(tr_mat, rz_mat)
        tf2 = torch.matmul(tf1, ry_mat)
        tf3 = torch.matmul(tf2, rx_mat)

        tr_local = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, x[0]],
                                [0, 1, 0, x[1]],
                                [0, 0, 1, x[2]],
                                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
        tf_output = torch.matmul(tf3, tr_local)
        output = tf_output[:3, 3]
        return output

    def get_loss(self, output):
        pass



model = Net()

input_ex = np.array([[-0.01, 0.05, 0.92],
                    [-0.06, 0.03, 0.94]])

output_ex = np.array([[-0.3, 0.4, 0.09],
                        [-0.5, 0.2, 0.07]])
print(list(model.parameters()))

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 0.001)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for input_np, label_np in zip(input_ex, output_ex):
    input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(input_np).float()
    label_tensor = torch.from_numpy(label_np).float()
    output = model(input_tensor)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = criterion(output, label_tensor)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(list(model.parameters()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happens

Your problem is related to PyTorch's implicit conversion of `torch.tensor` to `float`. Let's say you have this:

```
tr_mat = torch.tensor(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, self.params[3]],
        [0, 1, 0, self.params[4]],
        [0, 0, 1, self.params[5]],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
    ],
    requires_grad=True,
)
```

`torch.tensor` can only be constructed from list which has Python like values, it cannot have `torch.tensor` inside it. What happens under the hood (let's say) is each element of `self.params` which can be converted to `float` is (in this case all of them can, e.g. `self.params[3]`, `self.params[4]`, `self.params[5]`).

When `tensor`'s value is casted to `float` it's value is **copied** into Python counterpart hence **it is not part of computational graph anymore**, it's a new pure Python variable (which cannot be backpropagated obviously).

### Solution

What you can do is choose elements of your `self.params` and insert them into eye matrices so the gradient flows. You can see a rewrite of your `forward` method taking this into account:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.params = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(6))

    def forward(self, x):
        sinus = torch.cos(self.params)
        cosinus = torch.cos(self.params)

        tr_mat = torch.eye(4)
        tr_mat[:-1, -1] = self.params[3:]

        rz_mat = torch.eye(4)
        rz_mat[0, 0] = cosinus[2]
        rz_mat[0, 1] = -sinus[2]
        rz_mat[1, 0] = sinus[2]
        rz_mat[1, 1] = cosinus[2]

        ry_mat = torch.eye(4)
        ry_mat[0, 0] = cosinus[1]
        ry_mat[0, 2] = sinus[1]
        ry_mat[2, 0] = -sinus[1]
        ry_mat[2, 2] = cosinus[1]

        rx_mat = torch.eye(4)
        rx_mat[1, 1] = cosinus[0]
        rx_mat[1, 2] = -sinus[0]
        rx_mat[2, 1] = sinus[0]
        rx_mat[2, 2] = cosinus[0]

        tf1 = torch.matmul(tr_mat, rz_mat)
        tf2 = torch.matmul(tf1, ry_mat)
        tf3 = torch.matmul(tf2, rx_mat)

        tr_local = torch.tensor(
            [[1, 0, 0, x[0]], [0, 1, 0, x[1]], [0, 0, 1, x[2]], [0, 0, 0, 1]],
        )
        tf_output = torch.matmul(tf3, tr_local)
        output = tf_output[:3, 3]
        return output
```

(you may want to double check this rewrite but the idea holds).
Also notice `tr_local` can be done "your way" as we don't need any values to keep gradient.

### `requires_grad`

You can see `requires_grad` wasn't used anywhere in the code. It's because what requires gradient is not the whole eye matrix (we will not optimize `0` and `1`), but parameters which are inserted into it. Usually you don't need `requires_grad` **at all** in your neural network code because:

- input tensors are not optimized (usually, those could be when you are doing adversarial attacks or such)
- `nn.Parameter` requires gradient by default (unless frozen)
- layers and other neural network specific stuff requires gradient by default (unless frozen)
- values which don't need gradient (input tensors) going through layers which do require it (or parameters or w/e) can be backpropagated

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and excellent explanation. I edit my code following your instructions so now my code is running with no matters. I can be able to solve this problem quickly thanks to you!

Comment: @gus8cjf Accept the answer if the problem is resolved, thank you.